# Wordpress: How to Remove archive link on on Deault Wordress Calendar

Tags: wordpress, calendar, archive

I'm using the default Wordpress Calendar to display a simple calendar on the footer section of my website as shown in the following image.

[image]

the calendar is still showing a link to a page that display a archive of posts.

I do not need this links. I dont need to have an Event Calendar. I just want to display a Simple Calendar with the current day selected

Please, how can i deactivate this link from my calendar? Or is there another widget that i can use for this purpose?

I'm actually using the Appointement Blue Theme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use custom CSS and just hide it?

Comment: @AndriiPryimak That's not good for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

To display the current month with highlighted current day on it, you can use some calendar plugins like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/ where you don't need to add events and use widget to display calendar.

You might have to tweak some CSS to make as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jay . Unfortunately, this plugin is no longer available for download. is there another way to get it please?

Comment: Hi @blaiso if that plugin is not working you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/spiffy-calendar/ to achieve your requirement; I guess ;) please check

Comment: Thanks very much Jay. I used the mini-calendar widget of spiffy-calendar and it work properly for me. Thanks so much